# How to make argparse option undocumented?

Tags: python, argparse

How do I force an option to be undocumented in `argparse`, so it doesn't appear in the help text? Setting `help` to `None` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Set `help` to `argparse.SUPPRESS`:

```py
parser.add_argument('--test', action='store_true', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```